# ACF Как вывести все значения checkbox-ов на определенной странице?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Подскажите, пожалуйста как вывести все созданные значения определенного произвольного поля(не только checked) на кастомной странице в плагине [ACF](https://acfwp.ru/checkbox/)

Приведу пример, предположим на странице категории необходимо вывести Фильтры, по полю минимальные депозиты которые были назначены в админке разным постам.
[image: Минимальный депозит]

Если писать просто

```
<?php if(get_field("min_dep")) echo get_field("min_dep") ?>
```

То на странице категории оно выведет только зачёрканные элементы первой попавшейся страницы... А нужны все. Как найти этот массив значений ?

Так же пробую достучаться до внутренностей группы произвольных полей через запрос:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$group_ID = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE id = '49'" );
var_dump($group_ID);
 ?>
```

- где id это id поста acf плагина в админке. Но почему-то возвращает Стрингу `string(2) "49"` а не массив

Comment: Делаете `get_posts` для всех постов категории, складываете  в массив все значения `get_field("min_dep")` для найденных постов, потом уникализируете/сортируете - это решение влоб. Мб их апи позволяет сделать такое более элегантно

Comment: Может есть возможность как-то менее затратно?  Просто каждый раз обходить +100500 постов, удалять совпадение.... чёт как-то не очень звучит

Comment: Делать такой запрос, например, раз в сутки, его результаты где-то кешировать, для вывода на странице брать из кеша. Как вариант - захардкодить все возможные значения всех полей в фильтре, но тогда будет риск, что фильтр будет возвращать 0 результатов